# Variable might not be initialed

Tags: java, variables, exception

```
    while (a != true) {
            try {
                input = user_input.nextInt();

                calculate(input);
                a = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                user_input.next();
                System.out.println("fdsa");
            } catch (RangeException ex) {
            }

        }

        if (input == 1)
```

My problem is that i catch the exceptions i need which are if the input is <1 and >4 or a string and i print the error messages and the program asks me again to input a number between 1 and 4 but when i started implementing the exceptions the input variable on my if says that it might not be initialized. It's my first time implementing exceptions and i m having a hard time.

(edit)I solved the previous issue but i encountered a new unsolvable problem with scanner when i am typing an int between 1 and 4. This piece of my code is within another while loop which is currently infinite since it does not let me input again on the input=user_input.nextInt(); command and it is always repeating with the same value i initially typed. Thanks in advance and sorry for not posing my problem in a structured form.

Comment: As it suggests, initialise your variable..

Comment: please post an workable example and then point out what your expected output and what is the output you are getting

Comment: You can get rid of `a`. Change `while (a != true)` to `while (true)` and replace `a = true;` by `break`. Then the compiler will be smart enough to realise that `input` must have been given a value by the time you reach the `if (input == 1)` line.

Comment: I know it was not a well formatted question and i m sorry for that, Thanks for your answers you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot work out that the only way the loop exit is if `input` has been set. The simplest solution is to give it an initial value, or you could restructure your loop like this.

```
int input;
while (true) {
    try {
         input = user_input.nextInt();
         calculate(input);
         break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException | RangeException ex) {
         user_input.next();
    }
}
if (input == 1) // ok now.
```

Comment: can you please check the 2ond part  of my question please? I m having a problem with Scanner and the command nextInt()